# Rank + Countif formula not working correctly

Tags: excel, countif, rank, excel-2016, ranking-functions

[image][image]I have used this formula on excel for many years but its run into a problem

=RANK(B2,$B$2:$B$2461,0)+COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)-1

For some reason its not returning ranks 491, 492 and 519

Comment: Please could you add a screenshot of your data. Does it return rank 490 3 times and 518 twice?

Comment: Done, rows go down to 2461

Comment: Are all the costs definitely numeric?  I tried with a smaller set - 1 to 10.  If a unique number is treated as text it returns #N/A in the rank for that number.  If a number is not a duplicate and one instance is text and the other is numeric then my ranking goes from 1 to 9.  Not sure what's going on behind the scenes, but ranking is definitely mucked up.

Comment: Apologies, but could you add a screenshot of the rows with ranks 489, 490, 493, 494? Also, as @DarrenBartrup-Cook mentioned, please check the data type of each number using the TYPE function.

Comment: New screenshot added

Comment: "not returning ranks 491, 492 and 519" <-- could it be that there is a tie in the ranked values?